# coding a calculator is failling to apend values to the display

Tags: javascript

Am to programing I decided to try out a simple calculator app. but when i press key its failing to append the selected number to the display .. some help me check what wrong with my code

```
let calculator = document.querySelector("#calculator");
let keys = document.querySelector("#keys");
const display = document.querySelector("#answer");
//  links the clicked element.
keys.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches("div", "p")) {
    //adds event listener to key elements
    // alert(e.target.classList)
    const key = e.target;

    console.log(key);
    const action = key.dataset.action;
    const keyContent = key.textContent;
    const displayedNum = answer.textContent;
    if (!action && displayedNum === "0") {
      //feeds the number pressed to the display area
      answer.textContent = keyContent;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: can you give the html so we can run it?

Comment: e.target.matches looks wrong. `if (e.target.matches('div,p')){`

Comment: how do i add the html am new to these things

Comment: You can do it easily like this: ` answer.textContent += " " + keyContent;` The space is in there so the content is butted against each oher

Comment: are you calling the query before the dom is loaded?

Comment: let me try that @imvain2

Comment: i judt added everything to my github .. please hep me look through ..am stuck  
  github/izerque/test

Comment: so guy i found my problem ... the textContent method  returns all the content plus the white space. so it required triming

Comment: thankyou all for your help. see you around